# Phrase "Up in the stacks". What would this phrase mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

A textbook which introduces vocabularies that could appear on the day of the test (TOEFL) gives me a below sentence.

> It sounds like the staff at the circulation desk knows you pretty well. These days I'm mainly using the reserve desk and the reference section. My biology professor puts a lot of articles on reserve, and then there're these big reference volumes -- like The Encyclopedia Of Biology -- in the reference room that he wants us to read. You can't check those out. So I usually take them to a quiet desk **up in the stacks** and read them there.

I "conquered" several parts which are easy to native speakers, but I finally gave up when I came across the bold part. (Googling didn't help). Could you please help me what **up in the stacks** mean, in (probably) this context?

Comment: "staff" here is actually plural (it a rather odd noun) so it should be "...know you pretty well..."

Comment: Thank you. You know how much time I spend just for this sentence. Imagine if you come to Japan and go to our library and start reading like a "native" speaker. :9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means "**up around the bookshelves**". From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_stack):

> In library science and architecture, a *stack* or *bookstack* (often referred to as a library building's ***stacks***) is a book storage area, as opposed to a reading area.

And, from an ["Ask a Librarian" column](http://yorku.libanswers.com/a.php?qid=424984):

> 'Stacks' are the open shelves of library books. If the catalogue says a book is in the stacks, then it's on a shelf in the branch indicated in the catalogue.

The precise meaning of a preposition depends on the context. In this case, if a book is "up in the stacks," that means it's on the bookshelf, but if a person in "up in the stacks," that means they are sitting on a chair or at a table that is surrounded by bookshelves, or perhaps standing in the aisle looking at a book.

Comment: Ughhh...I knew what the word "stack" means "basically". ( piles, numbers of so on and so forth. ) But it could convey another meaning according to the context. Thanks!

Comment: The word has its own special meaning in a library, much like the word _memory_ might have a different meaning, depending on if you are a computer scientist or a neuroscientist.

Comment: _Stack_ can also mean 'a storage area for less-used books using [compact shelving](https://www.flickr.com/photos/uofglibrary/4369398483)'.